# Bootstrap 3 Horizontal Navbar Dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've looked at several methods of adding a horizontal like dropdown to bootstraps's navbar, but nothing seems to pan out. I am trying to acheive something like this across bootstraps fixed-top navbar.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/17/horizontal-slide-out-menu/

Can anyone let me know if you guys have had any luck doing this or have something simliar working?

Heres something Similar, but I'd like to add thumbnails across like the codrops example.

Comment: "Heres something Similar," ??? was that supposed to be a link ?

Answer (score 1):

Ive also been designing/searching for a bootstrap 3 horizontal menu that fits my needs. I stumbled across an example that might interest you.

Check [This](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm/) out... Click the "pictures" dropdown. Hope this helps